# Run a script prior to start of SQL instance via Windows clusters

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, sql, cluster

We have a Windows 2008 cluster with several SQL 2008 instance.  We would like to run a script that modifies 4 registry keys prior to the startup of SQL.  I do not know if there is a way to have a script run through Windows 2008 clustering that does that.  I have a VBS script to do it and tried to add a Generic Script to an existing cluster group, but it failed saying it could not be registered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The VBS script you use can't be just a generic VBS script - there are certain methods that it must implement (even if you just define the function and it does nothing). Perhaps this is your problem?

Check out [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373089(VS.85).aspx) page for some information on how to write a generic script and what functions you must implement.